# Where could I find the specific code for xtprobit in Stata?

Tags: matlab, panel, stata

I am trying to set up the likelihood function following Wooldridge (2005)'s dynamic probit estimator using Matlab (this is my first time using Matlab, and I am doing this for practice), but I am not sure how to  model the `integrating out a_i` part of the likelihood function, where

```
c_i (the random effect) = alpha0 + alpha1y_i0 + z_ialpha2 + a_i, a_i~normal(0, sigma_a^2).
```

Could someone give me a hint on how to do this?

I thought that I might get some idea from the "specific programming code" of the `xtprobit` Stata command. Could someone tell me where I could find them?

Comment: You can view ado code for commands in Stata with the `viewsource` command. In your case: `viewsource xtprobit.ado`.

Answer (score 1):

Check out page 17 in [the manual](http://www.stata.com/manuals13/xtxtprobit.pdf) for how the integration is done. Stata actually uses `xtgee` with the `binomial` family and `probit` link for the estimation, so that is probably the source code you want to emulate.